# Is there a way for komodo edit to highlight variables that start with a '$' dollarsign?

Tags: javascript, jquery, komodo, komodoedit

Is there a way for komodo to highlight variables that start with a '$' dollarsign?

An example would be variables like this: `var $btn;` 
 
I want to use these variables on javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Find dialog to do this:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> (or <kbd>Meta+F</kbd> in OSX)
- Click the `regex` checkbox
- Enter the pattern in the Find field: `\$[^\s]+`
- Click `Find All`

**References**

- [Komodo Search Actions](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/search.html#search_actions)
- [Komodo Regular Expressions Primer](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/regex-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Komodo has this functionality built-in; Check Preferences > Editor > Smart Editing > Variable highlighting.